# Inverse websockify

Tags: websocket

I'm looking for an inverse of websockify. So instead of proxying connections to a server that doesn't do WebSockets on its own (i.e. what websockify does), I want to connect to a WebSockets based thing with a client that doesn't grok WebSockets.

Does this exist?

Comment: On what server platform? Signalr can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see https://github.com/jimparis/unwebsockify/

> Unwebsockify is a TCP to WebSocket proxy/bridge. It accepts a plain TCP connection and connects to a WebSocket server, effectively adding WS support to a client that does not natively support it. It is essentially the opposite of websockify.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider .NET I would go for XSockets http://xsockets.net
You can connect to XSockets from anything that use TCP/IP.

Regards
Uffe